# How to automatically map values on a specific finit key set

Tags: python

For any value v that I give as input, the script automatically map it on a finite key sets ([a-z] for instance).

I tried something with `hash()` and `dict` but I don't find a function that realize the mapping automatically.

If for instance the inputs are

```
1, 1, 2
```

I want the output to be

```
a, a, b
```

How is the simplest way to do it in python ?

Comment: Are you looking for dictionaries? see: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: First, a dictionary can't have two same keys.

Comment: What is the problem with python dict? If I understand well your problem you can build a dict where the keys are the possible inputs and the values are the corresponding values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to write a function like that and use it for your inputs:

```
def get_char(i):
       if not isinstance(o,int):
               raise Exception('not int')
       if i not in range(1,27):
               raise Exception('out of range')
       return chr(i + (ord('a') - 1))
```

also read about [chr](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chr-in-python/) and [ord](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ord-function-python/) functions

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mapping function with a defined alphabet such as.

```
def mapping(i):
  alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  return alphabet[i]

for i in range(20):
  print(mapping(i))
```

Result# 
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t

Answer (score 0):

Use lists. To get the numbers:

```py
listofalphabets = ['a', 'b', 'c'....,'z']
result = []
inpt = input('Enter:  ')
for character in inpt:
    try:
        num = int(character)
        result.append(listofalphabets[num - 1]
    except:
        continue
print(result)
```

Haven't included error handling... include it.